# Make elements animate in from outside browser window with jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-animate

Howdy, I want to have an element slide into view from outside the browser window--the viewable div of my web page is 900px wide and is a box that floats in the center of the browser window. (So, if the browser window is 1100px across, there is 100px of blank space on either side of my 900px div. With a 1500px-wide browser window there 300px of blank space on either side, etc.)

What I want is to have an element slide in from the side so it enters the browser window, then moves across the empty space between the inside edge of the browser window and the outside edge of my 900px box and then enter the box (to be clear, all in one continuous motion).

This is easily done if I only have one size of browser window--I'd just have the element animate left by -=500px or so, but, if a viewer of my web site is using a larger screen, the element would start out inside the blank space instead of outside the browser window.

Of course, I could do something like animate left by -=1000px, but then that would mean people with a smaller screen are just waiting around for the element to appear as it crosses over the non-existent space of the non-existent area of the browser window.

So, my question is, **is there something I can tell jquery (or a plug-in) to do to set the starting point of a moving element just outside the visible edge of the browser window, regardless of the browser window's size?** Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to contain the entire animation inside a div that was wider than 1920px--the max screen size of my typical visitor--so that no matter what, the animated elements would appear by sliding in from the inside edge of the browser window on any monitor with a screen res of 1920px or smaller. With my previous answer, the elements appeared inside the 900px div. Now, I've created a div that is 1930px wide. And, I've added overflow:hidden to the body style to eliminate the horizontal scroll bar. Will test this weekend on a 1920px monitor...

Here's my latest test page with these changes implemented: http://ianmartinphotography.com/test-site/index.html

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you know the width of the fly-in node, set it to position absolute and make the left the negative of the width of the node.  Then, you need to calculate how far you want the node to animate.  Determine the current width of the browser, divide it by two, then subtract the width of the fly in node divided by two.  That'll be the left position where you want the node to end up.  So, the total distance it has to move would be the current left position of the fly in node added to the end position.  Fire your animate off of this number.  Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/brianflanagan/KtUEL/

Comment: Thank you Brian, I looked at your link and that's pretty interesting... I'll see if I can test it out and make it work...

Comment: Hi, Please take a look this test page and if you don't mind, please give me a hint at how you'd implement your solution. I have two elements that slide in, one from the left and other from the right. They meet inside my page, but not in the center... http://ianmartinphotography.com/test-site/index-left-right-10.html As it is now, a scroll bar appears and shrinks at the bottom of the page as the animation runs. (I've simply made my animation big enough for monitors of 1920px.) It'd be nice to use your solution so there wouldn't be that scroll bar... Thanks!

Comment: I should say I'm on a monitor smaller than 1920px, that's why the scroll bar appear... Haven't tested on a 1920px monitor yet...

Comment: Ah! overflow:hidden in the CSS of the parent div, the one that's 900px--no more scroll bar.

Comment: Yeah, you got it.  Looks nice, btw.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like what you really want is to know the page width. Take a look at this page, it will show you what browsers support what kind of page width properties:

http://www.softcomplex.com/docs/get_window_size_and_scrollbar_position.html

Answer (score 0):

So, What I wound up doing is just creating an animation wide enough for the biggest monitors that visit my site--1920px according to Google Analytics.

In the CSS of the parent div, #container, I've added overflow:hidden to prevent the scroll bar from appearing as the animation runs.

One thing that occurred to me (probably obvious to others) is that the duration of the animation dictates the speed at which the animated element moves across the screen--so, a moving element will take 1100ms to cross 10,000px or 1000px. Meaning, that the greater the distance the element has to travel, the faster it needs to move. Maybe there's a way to say: "Drive 60 miles an hour across this area." Instead, we say: "Cross this area in this amount of time and drive as fast as you have to to arrive on time."

I'll have a cookie set up so that this animation plays only once per session. To run it again, the cookie "welcome" will need to be cleared out, or, the browser will have to be quit and launched again. On this particular test page, the cookie is deactivated. http://ianmartinphotography.com/test-site/index-left-right-10.html

Comment: Here's a test page where the elements have to cross about 20,000 pixels in the same amount of time that they do in the test page of my answer--this time, they're moving a lot faster. http://ianmartinphotography.com/test-site/index-left-right-10-alt.html